# S3 Error unable to match signature for upload

Tags: swift, heroku, amazon-s3, alamofire

I'm trying to upload a file using a pre-signed request from heroku.

This is the pre-signed request I'm getting back from heroku:

```
{'url': u'https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/track134', 'track_id': 70, 
'x-amz-date': '20160928T162643Z', 'data': {'fields': {'acl': 'public-read', 
'signature': u'M9k2Ke9GsExvxvvhB17n6Y1uIiM=', 'policy': u'eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMTYtMDktMjhUMTc6MjY6NDNaIiwgImNvbmRpdGlvbnMiOiBbeyJhY2wiOiAicHVibGljLXJlYWQifSwgeyJDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiOiAiYXVkaW8vbXA0In0sIHsiYnVje9N0IjogImZ1dKMyZWZpbGVzIn0sIHsia2Z2IjogInRyYWNrMTM0In1dfQ==', 
'Content-Type': 'audio/mp4', 'AWSAccessKeyId': u'XXXXXXXXXXXX', 
'key': u'track134'}, 'url': u'https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/'}}
```

Using the values from above, I create this multipart form upload:

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
   multipartFormData.append(key.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "key")  // "track134"
   multipartFormData.append(acl.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "acl")  // "public-read"
   multipartFormData.append(contentType.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "Content-Type")  // "audio/mp4"
   multipartFormData.append(uuid.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "x-amz-meta-uuid")  //"14365123651274"
   multipartFormData.append(encryption.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "x-amz-server-side-encryption")  "AES256"
   multipartFormData.append(xamzcredential.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "X-Amz-Credential")  // "<AWSAccessKey>/20160928/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"
   multipartFormData.append(algorithm.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "X-Amz-Algorithm")  // "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"
   multipartFormData.append(isoDate.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "X-Amz-Date")  // "20160928T162643Z"
   multipartFormData.append(policy.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "Policy")  // "same as pre-signed request
   multipartFormData.append(signature.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "X-Amz-Signature")  // "same as pre-signed request
   multipartFormData.append(self.savedURL!, withName: "file", fileName: key, mimeType: contentType)  //key = "track134" contentType = "audio/mp4"
    },
    to: "https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/",
    encodingCompletion:{ encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseString { response in
                debugPrint(response)
        }
    case .failure(let encodingError):
        print(encodingError)
    }
}
)
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this 403 error:

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we 
calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing 
method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMTYtMDktMjhUMTc6MjY6NDNaIiwgImNvbmRpdGlvbnMiOiBbeyJhY2wiOiAicHVibGljLXJlYWQifSwgeyJDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiOiAiYXVkaW8vbXA0In0sIHsiYnVja2V0IjogImZ1dHVyZWZpbGVzIn0sIHsia2V5IjogInRyYWNrMTM0In1dfQ==</StringToSign>
<SignatureProvided>M9k2Ke9GsExvxvvhB17n6Y1uIiM=</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>
65 79 4a 6c 65 48 42 70 63 6d 46 30 61 57 39 75 49 6a 6f 67 49 6a 49 77 4d 54 59 74 4d 44 6b 74 4d 6a 68 55 4d 54 63 36 4d 6a 59 36 4e 44 4e 61 49 69 77 67 49 6d 4e 76 62 6d 52 70 64 47 6c 76 62 6e 4d 69 4f 69 42 62 65 79 4a 68 59 32 77 69 4f 69 41 69 63 48 56 69 62 47 6c 6a 4c 58 4a 6c 59 57 51 69 66 53 77 67 65 79 4a 44 62 32 35 30 5a 57 35 30 4c 56 52 35 63 47 55 69 4f 69 41 69 59 58 56 6b 61 57 38 76 62 58 41 30 49 6e 30 73 49 48 73 69 59 6e 56 6a 61 32 56 30 49 6a 6f 67 49 6d 5a 31 64 48 56 79 5a 57 5a 70 62 47 56 7a 49 6e 30 73 49 48 73 69 61 32 56 35 49 6a 6f 67 49 6e 52 79 59 57 4e 72 4d 54 4d 30 49 6e 31 64 66 51 3d 
3d</StringToSignBytes><RequestId>D232380DCEF794BE</RequestId>
<HostId>ly+8glzvyGtlO81QOrqNak7nAZngYZbD0upuSHUX07uT2FIz7OyztmM8wCVRXEfF3baIBIxtBK4=</HostId></Error>
```

I've been scouring the internet for hints to solving this but can't really hit on anything.  I'm hoping something sticks out to someone.

Couple notes:  I'm deriving the `X-Amz-Date` and `X-Amz-Credential` myself - not sure if thats how its suppose to work.  Also, I'm uploading an audio file that is m4a, I read the proper `Content-Type` for that would be `audio/mp4` and i'm setting `key` to the filename.